# redux sync localstorage state real time

Tags: reactjs, redux

I learn how to write state into localstorage from this video:
`https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage`

```
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

export const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore write errors.
  }
};
```

If I change a value in 'A' tab,and then I go to 'B' tab and refresh the page ,I can get the new value I changed on 'A' tab

But I want to know how to let 'B' tab get the new value without refresh page???

Comment: we need more code, post the A and B components with the switching logic

Comment: A and B is the same page

Comment: What do you mean tab? is it browser tab or navigate tab?